# IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute: ../DATA_WAREHOUSE/0_RAW/ASADI/raw_t_xd_diag_log_manually_car

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

`raw_t_xd_diag_log_manually_car = spark.read.format('parquet').load("../DATA_WAREHOUSE/0_RAW/ASADI/raw_t_xd_diag_log_manually_car").withColumn("vin", fn.concat(['whc_cd', 'lit','vehicle_id']))`

I am getting an error while running this code in Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct - you need to provide a full path or URI, like, `/mnt/my-data/...`, or `abfss://container@storage...../path` or something like that. But you're specifying the relative path that isn't resolvable because there is no notion of the current directory.